# First column non-zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,0,0], 'b':[0,1,2,0], 'c':[1,1,5,8]})
```

I would like to have another column storing the name of the first columns non-zero

```
   a  b  c  result    
0  0  0  1  c
1  2  1  1  a
2  0  2  5  b
3  0  0  8  c
```

Comment: Use `df.idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: However, what if a row has [0, 1, 2]? Should it return b (first non-zero) or c (largest number)?

Comment: It should return first non-zero

Comment: `df.ne(0).idxmax(1)
`

Comment: @Wen-Ben I have reopened, so you can write an answer :)

Comment: I am not sure what is your intention, but if you want to have another column that says if the first column is zero or not you can do this: df['non-zero'] = df [df['a'] !=0]. does it help?

Comment: @coldspeed no worry man , even with this `ne` still a simple dup question

Comment: Thanks @Wen-Ben, it's perfect